# "controlled by" vs "bounded by"

Tags: proof-writing, terminology

Suppose $A,B>0$ and there exists $C>0$ such that

$$A\leq C B.\qquad (1)$$

How express the fact (1) verbally?

Is it simply "$A$ is bounded by $B$" ?

or "$A$ is controlled by $B$" ?

Particularly, is saying "$A$ is controlled by $B$" equivalent to $(1)$ or equivalent to $A \leq B$ ?

Comment: Sorry, not really related to this question, but why did you delete [this question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4426383/is-this-simple-operator-bounded-from-lp1-2-to-lp0-1) I was just wondering , because I was reading it when it just disappeared!

Comment: By the way, over here I think "bounded" is better than controlled. As far as I've seen the use of the word controlled, it seems to consider bounds on *both* ends i.e. having two constants $C,C'$ such that $C'B\leq A \leq CB$. This makes more sense when $A,B$ are functions and $C,C'$ remain constants, in which case we have the big $O$ and related notations to express these relations.

Comment: Thanks for the comment on "controlled vs. bounded". Yes, I deleted the question you are referring to. I think I can refine it...

Comment: Oh, that's good to know. I'm following the question, so I'll see if I can say something about it when it comes up again.