# Is this simple operator bounded from $L^p([1,2])$ to $L^p([0,1])$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, inequality, harmonic-analysis

Let $f\in L^{p}([1,2])$ with $p>1$, and define
$$Tf(x):= \int_{1<y<2}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}dy,\quad 0<x<1.$$

I am trying to prove/disporove that

$$\|Tf\|_{L^p([0,1])}\leq C \|f\|_{L^p([1,2])}\quad (1)$$

I did not go far enough by Minkowski's integral inequality which implies

$$\left( \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{1<y<2}\frac{f(y)}{|x-y|}dy\right)^{p} dx \right)^{1/p}\leq \int_{1<y<2}f(y)\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(y-x)^{p}}\right)^{1/p}dy$$

One can estimate

$$\left(\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{(y-x)^{p}}\right)^{1/p}=\frac{1}{p-1}\left(\frac{1}{(y-1)^{p-1}}-\frac{1}{y^{p-1}}\right)^{1/p}\leq \frac{C}{(y-1)^{1-\frac{1}{p}}}$$
for $y$ close enough to $1$.

But this is not very helpful since
$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(y)}{(y-1)^{1-\frac{1}{p}}} dx$
is not bounded by $\|f\|_{L^{p}([1,2])}$ considering the counterexample $g_{p}(x):=\frac{\chi_{[1,3/2]}(x)}{|\log{(x-1)}|(x-1)^{\frac{1}{p}}}$.

Comment: Would it help to write $Tf(x)=\int^2_0\mathbb{1}_{(1-x,2-x]}(y)\frac{f(y+x)}{y}\,dy$, where $f(y)$ is define to be $0$ outside $(1,2)$?

Comment: Nice formulation, but I don't know how useful it can be.. Do you have a certain singular operator in mind ?

Comment: Not really, but it does separate differently when you apply the generalized Monkowski intequalty. That may give you some other exponent $q$ in $L_q[0,1]$

Comment: Yes, but we still end up with something like $\int_{0}^{2}y^{-1}dy$.

Comment: I really appreciate your interest. There is no room for Holder's inequality and I don't know how to build on your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it seems that it going to be similar to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: I can type an answer if you are not going to remove the question, as you did the other day.

Comment: @ Ryszard Szwarc  The question is here to stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $(Sf)(x)=f(x+1)$ and $(Rf)(x)=f(1-x).$ Then $S$ and $R$ are isometries from $L^p(1,2)$ to $L^p(0,1)$ and $L^p(0,1)$ to $L^p(0,1),$ respectively. Observe that $T=RPHS, $ where
$$(Hf)(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty {f(y)\over y+x}\,dy$$
and $P$ is the restriction operator from $L^p(0,\infty)$ to $L^p(0,1).$

It suffices to show that the operator $H$ is bounded. The operator $H$ is a continuous version of the Hilbert matrix. By substitution $y={tx}$ we get $$(Hf)(x)=\int\limits_0^\infty {f(tx)\over 1+t}\,dt$$
Let $(H_tf)(x)=f(tx).$ Then $\|H_tf\|_p=t^{-1/p}\|f\|_p.$ Hence $$\|Hf\|_p\le \int\limits_0^\infty {1\over (1+t)t^{1/p}}\,dt\ \|f\|_p$$
Therefore $$\|T\|\le \int\limits_0^\infty {1\over (1+t)t^{1/p}}\,dt$$

Comment: ELEGANT answer!  But shouldn't the restriction operator $P$ act on $f$ before the Hilbert operator  $H$ ?

Comment: No, because $Sf$ belongs to $L^p(0,1),$ so the restriction is not needed.

Comment: I was thinking of a point-wise operator that goes $Pf (x)=\chi_{[0,1]}(x)f(x)$. But, I get it now, you are restricting the operator $H$ to a subspace. Okay. Thanks

Comment: If you would like to be very formal, you can add, after $S,$ the inclusion operator from $L^p(0,1)$ to $L^p(0,\infty).$

Comment: Or do without the restriction $P$ altogether and prove the inequality for the larger operator $Tf=\int_1^\infty \frac{f(y)}{y-x}dy$, $0<x<1$ :)

Comment: Hi @Oliver It worked!! I am glad I could help.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: I appreciate the support, thank you!